# How to apply a 2D boolean array on a 3D dask array in python

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I have a boolean array A of size (5250, 3) and another dask array D of size (5250, 6850, 3).
I am trying to do D[A]. But it is giving the error

> NotImplementedError: Slicing with dask.array of bools only permitted when the indexer has only one dimension or when it has the same dimension as the sliced array`

How to apply 2D boolean array on 3D dask array?

Comment: How about multiplying the arrays?

Comment: can you show us your code? `dask.array.mask(arr, mask)` works for me with similar dimensions.